# How do you give an object a solid color in the render?

Tags: rendering

I want to have a part of my render be a very specific color, for the whole object. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @brockmann yes thank you i am sorry for asking the question

Comment: No problem, glad it helps. Otherwise please use the [edit] link at the 
bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add 
more information on how you set up your project.
[Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that 
might help us understand your scene and settings. See [How to upload 
an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491). 
Consider sharing your .blend file so that others can inspect it. You 
can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then 
paste the resulting link as part of your question.